# mvc entity framework many to many user and role insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have an mvc project with database first entityframework. In Project I have 3 tables.

Users >>> UsersInRoles <<< Roles  with many to many relationship.

and my CreateUser codes below;

```
public bool CreateUser(string email, string password, string birthday,string firstname,string lastname)
    {
        bool result;
        var dogumgunu = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
        var sifre = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "sha1");
        var confirmation = CreateConfirmationToken(email);
            try
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    UserName = email,
                    Password = sifre,
                    UserJoinDate = DateTime.Now,
                    UserBirthDay = dogumgunu,
                    UserConfirmationToken = confirmation,
                    UserID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    MemberFirstName = firstname,
                    MemberLastName = lastname
                };
                var role = new Role
                {
                    RoleName = "Client"
                };
                user.Roles.Add(role); //problem is here!!!!!!!!!
                _bb.Users.AddObject(user);
                _bb.SaveChanges();
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                result = false;
            }


        return result;
    }
```

In this code I am new user creating. And I am adding a role. But This code include a new Role in Roles table. I dont want to this. I want to just add UsersInRoles table a new user. What is wrong? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap these two lines:

```
_bb.Users.AddObject(user);
user.Roles.Add(role);
```

because `AddObject` converts the whole object graph to the `Added` state. If you add the role afterwards, its state will remain `Unchanged`.

And you should fetch the role from the database first or create a `Role` object that only has an existing `RoleId`. (A so called *stub entity*).

So in stead of `new Role` you could do

```
var role = _bb.Roles.Single(r => r.RoleName == "Client");
```

Comment: thanks gert but ı cant understand. please tell me how can I add a role in my UsersInRoles table?

Comment: I see it. But I can understand. please write a small sample? thanks for helps. and I am sorry my stopid.:)

Comment: God bless you gert. Thanks for everything.